# Les vidéos de « teardown » d'appareils électroniques ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, terminologie, synonymes

On peut trouver des vidéos (de [*teardown*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/teardown?s=ts)) où l'on s'intéresse à ce qu'il y a dans différents appareils, aux choix des composants, aux circuits, à la facture du montage etc. (par ex. [*photocopier teardown*](https://youtu.be/WSxEGgrvhMM)). On trouve le terme [*démontage*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9montage) associé à l'[aéronautique](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18967371), au [travail des métaux](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8402355) ou plus généralement au domaine [technique et aux sciences](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=TEARDOWN&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs), ainsi qu'à un ensemble d'[autres termes](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=DEMONTAGE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) techniques en langue anglaise (*stripping, take down, [disassembly](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8402355), roll-up*) etc.

- S'agit-il bien techniquement/couramment de *vidéos de démontage d'appareils électroniques* ?
- Le *démontage* ([démonter](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9monter)) et *désassemblage* ([désassembler](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9sassembler))
  sont-ils tous les deux aussi adéquats pour exprimer ce dont il est
  question ici ; le désassemblage vise-t-il toujours surtout [le bois](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/d%C3%A9sassembler/24242) ?
- Y a-t-il des (d'autres) synonymes ou d'autres manières de décrire ce
  dont il s'agit en employant un autre terme ou une locution ou autrement ?

Comment: "le désassemblage vise-t-il toujours surtout le bois ?" Je ne sais pas pour l'électronique, mais on utilise volontiers "désassembler" dans le contexte de l'ingénierie logicielle (typiquement dans une démarche de rétro-ingénierie, un peu comme le "teardown").

Comment: Peut-être qu'il y a une question à poser sur la différence entre _désassembler_ et _décompiler_ en informatique. Est-ce que _désassembler_ peut vouloir aussi dire revenir à du langage assembleur etc. ? Est-ce que le démontage est plus ou moins opaque que la rétro-ingénierie etc. ? Merci. @mcadorel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Démonter/démontage* et *désassembler/désassemblage* décrivent très bien ces actions.

**Démonter** est d'usage beaucoup plus courant, **désassembler** est plus technique.

Désassembler peut très bien s'appliquer à d'autres objets que ceux en bois.

Il existe quelque synonymes pouvant plus ou moins correspondre à ce type de vidéo, mais ils sont beaucoup plus rarement utilisés dans ce contexte :

- désosser (argotique)
- démanteler (l'objet démantelé est destiné à être détruit)
- disséquer (l'objet est assimilé à un être vivant)
- décortiquer (familier)

Comment: ainsi qu'un très passe-partout : *défaire*.

Comment: @aCOSwt Ouais.. pas trop dans ce contexte. Je me vois mal dire *j'ai défait la photocopieuse...*

Comment: Non effectivement mais j'ai défait son capot puis défait le câblage de la lampe... Maintenant oui il n'est pas tip top, ce d'autant qu'il ne se prête pas volontiers à la substantivation.

Comment: @aCOSwt défaisage ? défaction ? ...

Comment: Par cohérence avec les autre, j'inventerais *défaçon*, mais ici plutôt *rétrofaçon*. En fait, ce qui me tentait avec *défaire* est cette idée que l'on retrouve justement avec *démonter* et *désassembler* que l'on retrouverait aussi avec *déconstruire* mais pas dans tes 4 dernières alternatives : L'idée de procéder à l'envers du processus de construction.

Comment: Ha! Tiens! Et pourquoi pas ***déshabiller / déshabillage***. Après tout... le gugusse, il ne fait guère qu'enlever la coque et quelques accessoires. Il ne dessoude pas les composants fondamentaux. (Je sais que cela se disait ainsi chez Ligier quand on n'allait pas jusqu'à toucher au moteur)

Comment: Merci, par curiosité, le _désosser_, c'est le même que _désosser une cuisse de poulet_ ou c'est un tout autre sens que ça ? Si je disais l'_inspection des composants (internes) d'un appareil_, inspiré par [ceci](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18967371), est-ce que l'on s'imagine qu'on ouvre l'appareil ou que l'on présente des composants neufs qui s'y trouveraient, à titre démonstratif, ou est-ce que l'on glisse vers la [_nomenclature_](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8381192) (_bill of material_) ?

Comment: Oui, c'est le même [désosser, au sens figuré](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9sosser). "Inspection des composants" s'applique plus à des composants en cours d'utilisation et n'implique pas de démontage, plutôt l'ouverture de protections ou capots le cas échéant.